# Grouping subsets within ordered data in SQL

Tags: sql, grouping, hana, gaps-and-islands

I have a data set of manufacturing operations.  During some parts of the process, there may be steps that can be completed in parallel, meaning they can be completed in any order and may even overlap.  In the sample below, for example, steps 2, 3, and 4 for order 1001 can be done in any order.  Type = C notates a parallel operation.

Because historical data may show parallel steps completed in any order, I would like to treat each block of C steps as a single row and use the minimum start and maximum end time within that group as shown in the desired table.

How may I achieve this in SQL?  Specifically HANA SQL but any relevant example will help.

Current:

```
+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| order_nbr | step | type |        start        |         end         |
+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1001 |    1 | P    | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 |
|      1001 |    2 | C    | 2021-01-04 03:00:00 | 2021-01-04 06:00:00 |
|      1001 |    3 | C    | 2021-01-03 07:00:00 | 2021-01-03 08:00:00 |
|      1001 |    4 | C    | 2021-01-05 10:00:00 | 2021-01-05 15:00:00 |
|      1001 |    5 | Z    | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 2021-01-06 06:00:00 |
|      1001 |    6 | Z    | 2021-01-06 16:00:00 | 2021-01-06 20:00:00 |
|      1001 |    7 | C    | 2021-01-07 08:00:00 | 2021-01-07 09:00:00 |
|      1001 |    8 | C    | 2021-01-07 10:00:00 | 2021-01-07 12:00:00 |
|      1002 |    1 | P    | 2021-01-04 08:00:00 | 2021-01-04 16:00:00 |
+-----------+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Desired:

```
+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| order_nbr |  step   | type |        start        |         end         |
+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1001 | 1       | P    | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 |
|      1001 | 2, 3, 4 | C    | 2021-01-03 07:00:00 | 2021-01-05 15:00:00 |
|      1001 | 5       | Z    | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 2021-01-06 06:00:00 |
|      1001 | 6       | Z    | 2021-01-06 16:00:00 | 2021-01-06 20:00:00 |
|      1001 | 7, 8    | C    | 2021-01-07 08:00:00 | 2021-01-07 12:00:00 |
|      1002 | 1       | P    | 2021-01-04 08:00:00 | 2021-01-04 16:00:00 |
+-----------+---------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Grouped concatentation? Like `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server

Comment: To get the concatenation, yes, but not sure how to selectively group blocks of Type C rows.

Comment: `GROUP BY order_nbr, type, CASE WHEN type <> 'C' THEN step ELSE NULL END` then you select `order_nbr, type, step = STRING_AGG(step), start = MIN(start), end = MIN(end)`

Comment: Within a single order, for example 1001, there are two blocks of Cs that must be independently grouped.  If I'm running that snippet correctly it returns a single row for all Cs within order 1001 in the final result.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that bit. You would have to use some kind of `ROW_NUMBER` scheme to group the items. See [Itzik Ben-Gan](https://livebook.manning.com/book/sql-server-mvp-deep-dives/chapter-5/15) and [here also](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions) on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a gaps and islands problem, as was [commented earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584550/grouping-subsets-within-ordered-data-in-sql#comment115958051_65584550), so you can check the linked articles to deep dive into the problem. But you need to group your data conditionally after finding islands (where you need to collapse only `type = 'C'` items.

Here's the code:

```
with s as (
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '1' as step, 'P' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-01 00:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-01 09:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '2' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-04 03:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-04 06:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '3' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-03 07:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-03 08:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '4' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-05 10:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-05 15:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '5' as step, 'Z' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-06 00:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-06 06:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '6' as step, 'Z' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-06 16:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-06 20:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '7' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-07 08:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-07 09:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '8' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-07 10:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-07 12:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1002' as order_nbr, '1' as step, 'P' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-04 08:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-04 16:00:00' as end_ts from dummy
)
, num as (
  select
    s.*
    /*Find consecutive rows on ex_type field*/
    , row_number() over(partition by order_nbr order by start_ts asc) as r1
    , row_number() over(partition by order_nbr, ex_type order by start_ts asc) as r2
  from s
)
select
  order_nbr
  , ex_type
  , min(start_ts) as start_ts
  , max(end_ts) as end_ts
  , string_agg(step, ',' order by start_ts asc) as steps
from num
group by
  order_nbr
  , ex_type
  , case
      /*For C use group number, for others - use original row number not to collapse them*/
      when ex_type = 'C'
      then r1 - r2
      else r1
  end
order by 
  order_nbr
  , start_ts asc
```

And here's [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=dc843f3184cf74e6c620ac42f4cae0da) on PostgreSQL as HANA-syntactically identical platform for involved functions.

Comment: That's great, thank you!  Here is my ugly caveman [approach](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=487dad5ccc87ceea127b27a439c73971) I tried yesterday and just adapted to your exact dataset to compare.  I thought of creating an id field that changes with each row unless the C type is repeated.  I like your cleaner looking solution better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach before using the answer provided by astentx which creates an id for non-C rows and groups of type C rows.

```
with s as (
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '1' as step, 'P' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-01 00:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-01 09:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '2' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-04 03:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-04 06:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '3' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-03 07:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-03 08:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '4' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-05 10:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-05 15:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '5' as step, 'Z' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-06 00:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-06 06:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '6' as step, 'Z' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-06 16:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-06 20:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '7' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-07 08:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-07 09:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1001' as order_nbr, '8' as step, 'C' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-07 10:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-07 12:00:00' as end_ts from dummy union all
  select '1002' as order_nbr, '1' as step, 'P' as ex_type, timestamp '2021-01-04 08:00:00' as start_ts, timestamp '2021-01-04 16:00:00' as end_ts from dummy
)


select
    b.order_nbr,
    b.ex_type,
    min(b.start_ts) as start_ts,
    max(b.end_ts) as end_ts,
    string_agg(b.step, ',') as steps
from
    (select
        a.order_nbr,
        a.step,
        a.ex_type,
        a.start_ts,
        a.end_ts,
        sum(a.inc) over (order by a.order_nbr asc, a.start_ts asc) as id
    from
        (select
            s.order_nbr,
            s.step,
            s.ex_type,
            s.start_ts,
            s.end_ts,
            case
                when s.ex_type = 'C' and s.ex_type = lag(s.ex_type) over (partition by s.order_nbr order by s.start_ts)
                    then 0
                    else 1
                end as inc
            from
                s
            order by
                s.order_nbr asc,
                s.start_ts asc
        ) as a
    ) as b
group by
    b.order_nbr,
    b.ex_type,
    b.id
order by
    b.order_nbr asc,
    min(b.start_ts) asc
```